# Re: how can I get the rank and total of rows in a MySQL table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Good morning gurus, I posted the below yesterday and I was told that similar question has been raised and answered. Please, can anyone give me the link to the similar answer given? Thanks

```
I'd.  Regno.  Class.    Subject      Score   
1.     111.      JSS1.    Mth.            60
2.     112.       JSS1.    Mth.           50
3.      111        JSS1.    Eng.          60
4.      112.       JSS1.    Eng.          80 etc
```

Please, how can I use Php and MySQL to use the above records to get the below records?

```
Regno.   Eng.      Math.    Total.    Position
111.        60.         60.         120.       2nd
112.        80.         50.          130.      1st
```

Comment: This is a standard pivot, and you've already been told precisely where to look. That said, to my mind, these issues are best resolved in application code

Comment: Just follow the link at the top of your previous question, no need to post the same question again

Answer (score 0):

It's clunky, but it does the job.  If you have many subjects, then it will get out of control, and you'll have to do something more advanced.

```
select t.*
, rank() over (order by total) as ranking
from    (
select regno
, sum(case when subject = 'Mth.' then score end) as math
, sum(case when subject = 'Eng.' then score end) as eng
, sum(score) as total
from test.scores
group by regno
) t
```

For reference: test.scores is your input table